# What formula to use on this continuous uniform distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Question:

"In a marble game, players select marbles at random from a box containing a large number of marbles with different weights. The weight, in grams, of a randomly chosen marble has a continuous uniform distribution over the range [7, 10].

To win a prize, a player must select 6 marbles and wins a prize if more than 4 of the marbles weigh less than 7.6 grams. Find the probability of winning a prize."

How do I start working on this question? Can't use binomial distribution since that's only for discrete random variables.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_i$ be $1$ if the weight of the $i-$the marble is less that $7.6$ gram and $0$ otherwise. Note that the $X_i$ are independents. Set $$S_6=X_1+...+X_6.$$
Then $$\mathbb P\{win\}=\mathbb P\{S_6>4\}=\sum_{i=5}^6\binom{6}{i}p^i(1-p)^{6-i},$$
where $p=\mathbb P\{X_i=1\}.$

Comment: "More than $3$" I guess. Or "at least $4$".

Comment: @drhab: thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

> "Can't use binomial distribution..."

Yes you can.

To be found is $P(X>4)$ where $X$ has binomial distribution with parameters $n=6$ and $p=P(M<7.6)$.

Here $M$ stands for the weight of chosen marble so has continuous distribution over range $[7,10]$.

Comment: `P(X<7.6)=(7.6-7) * 1/3 = 0.2`      `P(X>4) = P(X=5) + P(X=6) = (6C5 * 0.2^5 * 0.8^1) + (6C6 *0.2^6 *0.8^0) =  0.0016 `     However, the correct answer should be  `0.0126`. Not sure what I did wrong here.

Comment: $p=0.2$ is correct. Are you sure of $>4$? Maybe they mean $\geq4$ (I haven't calculated anything).

Comment: Yeah the question stated MORE THAN 4 marbles, not MORE THAN OR EQUAL TO 4 marbles.

Comment: Your calculation looks fine to me. Let's hope that the book is wrong then.